# What is the difference between physical and logical cores in a CPU/microprocessor?

Tags: cpu-architecture, terminology, processor, hyperthreading, cpu-cores

I try to understand below terms but still having confusion on it

- microprocessor
- processor
- cores
- processor cores
- physical cores
- logical cores

To my knowledge

> microprocessor (CPU) == processor
>
> Every system is having only one processor but we can have more cores
>
> But what is the difference between processor and core ?
>
> What is physical cores and logical cores ?

Please explain it.

Comment: multiprocessor and multicpu are probably the same depending who you ask. Processor and CPU are often used interchangeably (ignoring the difference between physical and logical cores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Microprocessors may have multiple cores, think of a core as a unit of computation, for example: the original Pentium processor had just one core in one chip, in these days is possible to have multiple cores in one chip (like a Core i7), that is the Multi-core processor.

Some people refers to physical cores to the number of absolute cores in the chip, but there is another technology called multi-threading that allows to run [multiple threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) in the same pipeline of the core, taking advantage of the duplication of processing units P.U. let me try to clarify, for example a Core i7 from Intel, has (at least some models) 4 cores inside the same chip or multiprocessor and also every core can run 2 threads simultaneously, you can think of a "logical core as" a thread it is a programming abstraction. So basically you can have 8 concurrent threads in a Core i7 with 4 cores with Multi-threading.

Hope this helps to clarify, Wikipedia you can read more in depth.

Answer (score 5):

"Multiprocessor" and "multi-cpu" mean the same thing.

As the electronic circuits for a "CPU" got more complex, utilization decreased. For an example; you might have huge circuits for handling floating point arithmetic doing nothing because the code being executed only uses integers. For another example; the entire CPU might have to wait for data to come from RAM (due to a cache miss or branch misprediction) and sit doing nothing for hundreds of cycles.

Around 20+ years ago manufacturers realized that, with a few modifications, the "almost same" electronic circuits could pretend that there are 2 (or more) "CPUs"; and improve the utilization of the underlying electronic circuits. To avoid confusion/ambiguity (what does "CPU" mean?) they changed the terminology - the name of the underlying group of electronic circuits was changed from "CPU" to "core", and new names ("logical processor", "hardware thread") where created to describe those "pretend CPUs sharing the same circuits/core".

A common laptop might have a total of 2 cores and a total of 4 logical processors; so each core has 2 logical processors (or each separate group of electronic circuits pretends that there are 2 CPUs). The word "CPU" is still ambiguous - someone from 1980 might look at the electronic circuits in your laptop and say that you have 2 CPUs, and a software developer from 2020 might look at how many pieces of code can be executed simultaneously on your laptop and say that you have 4 CPUs; and neither of these answers ("You have 2 CPUs and 4 CPUs") would be wrong.

To confuse this even more; originally "CPU" literally meant "the central unit that does processing". With integrated circuits this led to "CPU" being used as a synonym for a physical chip within a computer; but as integrated circuits got larger and cheaper we started seeing computers with 2 or more processors each on separate chips in the computer (where none can truly be considered "central"); and then started seeing 2 or more processors on the same chip. The change in terminology (primarily from "CPU" to "core") helps to fix that ambiguity too. Going back to the laptop example used above, "You have 1 CPU and 2 CPUs and 4 CPUs" would be extremely confusing, but "You have one physical chip containing 2 cores and 4 logical processors" has no ambiguity.