# What does it mean when we say "4 cores 8 threads"?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

When I run `lscpu` on my host, it shows

```
CPU(s):                8
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
```

My host has 4 physical CPUs, but 8 logical CPUs due to 2 threads per core. ok, "2 threads per core" means one core can execute 2 threads simultaneously so as if we have doubled the CPU capacity? So this is **parallel** concept?

While we have another concept that "one process can have multiple threads", I believe this means one process can handle multiple threads **concurrently** by switching context, but not necessarily in **parallel**. In most cases one CPU can execute one thread at a time, right?

I'd like to confirm my understanding above is correct. Thanks

Ref for concurrent and parallel difference: [What is the difference between concurrency and parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism/)

Comment: It's just Intel HyperThreading marketing stuff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It's not "just marketing", Hyper Threading is the brand name Intel uses for their SMT (Simultaneous Multi-Threading).  That's a useful CPU-architecture feature for *some* use-cases, especially on really wide CPUs with lots of execution units.

Comment: Related: [What is a CPU thread and how is it related to logical threads in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916048) / [SMT and Hyperthreading : threads vs process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46793813) also addresses the terminology of software thread vs. logical core (confusingly sometimes called a "hardware thread") / [What is the difference between physical and logical cores in a CPU/microprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23004555).   Also the SMT / Hyperthreading section of **http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/**

Comment: Also [What is a "Logical CPU Core"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23935539)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concept is called [Simultaneous multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (SMT). It is implemented in many processor, from x86-64 (both AMD and Intel) to POWER. The idea is to execute 2 threads *concurrently*. Some operation can be parallel regarding the specific target architecture.

> one core can execute 2 threads simultaneously so as if we have doubled the CPU capacity?

No. Hardware threads (also called logical cores) are not equivalent to cores (ie. in opposition to physical cores). Some processor units are statically allocated for the hardware threads while some units are dynamically allocated for the hardware thread meaning the threads share the available resources.

The initial idea was to execute something useful when a core was stalling on some operations like memory reads. With 2 hardware threads, a core can execute the instructions of another thread if the current one is waiting on memory, for example due to a cache miss. Memory-bound parallel codes that are limited by the latency of the RAM like naive transpositions or linked-list traversals can benefit from this mechanism.

The SMT implementation has significantly improved over time. Especially in x86-64 processor recently. Nowadays, hardware threads of modern processor can execute computing instructions truly in *parallel*. For example, an Intel Skylake processor can execute up to 4 arithmetic instructions at a time per cycle, thanks to 4 [ALUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit). 1 thread can execute 4 instructions per cycle only if the instructions are independent (during the target cycles). This is not always possible as some loops are inherently sequential and do not contain enough independent instruction for each loop (eg. cumulative sum). With a 2-way SMT enabled, 2 software threads can be scheduled on the same core and the core can execute 2 instructions of each thread completely in parallel in a given cycle. It can even load balance the number of instruction regarding the needs of each thread in real time (eg. 1 vs 3 instructions per cycle). In the end, **latency-bound codes can be up to 2 times faster** on a 2-way SMT processor like Skylake. That being said, it does **not speed up codes that can already fully use all the available processor computing units**. For example, a parallel matrix multiplication using an optimized BLAS library will nearly always be slower with 2 software threads running per core than with only 1 software thread per core. The execution can be slower because hardware thread share some resources like caches and they can conflict each other with 2 threads per core running simultaneously. Put it shortly, efficient codes should not benefit from it, but people tends to write inefficient code and it is not rare for compilers to fail to generate efficient codes saturating computing units of a core (they often need some help).

> While we have another concept that "one process can have multiple threads", I believe this means one process can handle multiple threads concurrently by switching context, but not necessarily in parallel.

I would like to set the record straight: **software threads and hardware threads are two very different things** despite the name.

A [software thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) is a logical OS unit that can be scheduled on a hardware thread. A hardware thread can be seen as a physical part of a processor core (it is actually a naive simplistic view). A software thread is a part of an OS process. The OS is responsible for the scheduling of the ready software threads. Processes are not scheduled, software threads are (at least on a modern OS). 2 software threads of 2 different processes can run in parallel on a processor with multiple cores (or even on some 2-way SMT cores).

> In most cases one CPU can execute one thread at a time, right?

The term "CPU" is not clear here: it can mean different things regarding the context.

If "one CPU" means a modern microprocessor chip that is typically a multicore one nowadays, then definitively **no**. Software threads can truly run in parallel on different cores for examples.

If "one CPU" means a core (like often in high-performance computing), then it depends: a 1-way SMT core can execute only 1 thread at a time while a 2-way SMT core can execute 2 thread at a time.

On old microprocessor chip with 1 core and no SMT, it was true that one thread was running at a time and context switches was used to execute thread concurrently from the user point-of-view but not in parallel. This time is long gone (since nearly 2 decades) except maybe on some embedded microprocessor chips.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this...parallel?

Maybe.

[*Hyperthreading*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is Intel's trademark* for processor cores that have two complete sets of context registers. A hyperthreaded CPU can concurrently execute code on behalf of two threads without any intervention by the operating system (i.e., with no need for [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).)

The extent to which those two concurrent executions actually are *parallel* executions varies from CPU model to model, and it depends on what the two threads actually are doing. For example (I'm just making this part up because it's been a few decades since I've needed to worry about any particular CPU architecture) if some "hyperthreaded" CPU has two integer ALUs per core, then the two threads might both be able to perform integer operations in parallel, but if it has only one FPU per core, then they would have to take turns using it.

Some Hyperthreaded CPU models have more duplicate [*execution units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_unit) than others have, and so can parallelize more parts of the execution.

---

* AMD calls their similar capability, "2-way simultaneous multithreading."

Comment: 2-way SMT is also an accurate description of what Intel does on their cores with HT enabled.  And yeah, most back-end resources are competitively shared, with the front-end alternating between logical cores unless one is stalled.  Modern AMD and Intel CPUs are pretty similar in terms of how they do SMT, only replicating a few resources, mostly sharing either statically partitioning or competitively / dynamically letting one thread use more.  e.g. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Individual_Core has a colour-coded block diagram of a Zen 2 core.