# Is it legal to use Amdahl's law in the inverse way? How many threads should I use?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, parallelism-amdahl

I run many times an OpenMP code for an increasing number of threads P1,P2,P3,....,P15 and for each thread number Pi, I estimated experimentally the corresponding speedup S1,S2,....,S15 by dividing the serial execution time with the corresponding parallel execution time. As it was expected by Amdahl's law, the speedup gain is progressively decreased and if this experiment continues to be executed infinitely, the upper speedup bound will be reached, according to Amdahl's law.

(a) Is it possible to use the pairs (Pi,Si) (i=1,2,...15), to estimate the serial fraction of calculations? If I solve the Amdahl's law with respect to f (the serial fraction) I can use the values of (Pi,Si) to get the corresponding fi value (i=1,2,...,15). These values are almost the same (if i remember correctly equal to 0.0015 or something like that) since the code is embarrassingly parallel. How can I use these values? I can get their average or something like that? I want to estimate the serial fraction, that due to the nature of the problem I suppose that it is associated with thread scheduling.

(b) how many threads I have to use? my CPU (Intel Core i5) supports 20 hardware threads. I stopped to 15 threads and I can go to 20, but what next? 30? 40? 50? If I can estimate the serial fraction of the previous question i can estimate the upper speedup as 1/fi.

Comment: The simplest way is by experimental observation. Starting with 1 thread keep doubling until you can see the pattern and then try 1.5x, etc to fill in the gaps where the transition to going memory bandwidth limited occurs. In extremis adding more cores beyond a certain point to some problems like chess can actually slow things down. You can reach a point where adding another CPU core merely increases heat output for no measurable decrease in computation time.  There is usually a sweet spot with less than all possible cores/threads utilised.

Comment: *"how many threads I have to use?"* You should never have more active threads than hardware thread. If you do, then there will be scheduling issues and this is generally very bad for computing application (especially the one using the common fork-join model). In practice, using 2 threads per core may not result in a performance improvement because 1 thread can sometimes saturate a core. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74408140/what-does-it-mean-when-we-say-4-cores-8-threads/74408976#74408976) for more information about SMT. This is dependent of the target application.

Comment: On Intel big-little CPUs (I guess you use such a CPU), P-cores can have 2 hardware threads while E-core have one. This helps to load-balance the work between cores and better use P-cores so it is generally a good thing. Still, a well written optimized application may not need that : it can use tasks scheduling (with dependencies) to load balance the work while avoiding synchronisation barriers, and unroll loops as well as prefetching to increase the ILP (reducing the benefit of the SMT). This is not easy to do and most applications don't currently do that.

Comment: *"estimate the serial fraction of calculations"* Based on the previous comments, we can conclude that the execution time can be limited by complex effects (synchronizations/load-balancing, instruction scheduling, OS scheduling, resource contention, etc.). Technically, while a significant part of the slow down (but not all of it) is often due to a kind serial execution, but not just a fraction of sequential user-code execution. Thus, I think the number you will get from this calculation is rather meaningless in the end...

Comment: By the way, the Amdahl's law assume the parallel code is completely parallel and there is a fully sequential part. However, in practice, application do not use either 1 or N threads (again due to the work-imbalance). Moreover, the N threads are rarely N times faster due to the resource contention and thermal limitations. The later effect is a good example of a slow-down not caused by a serial execution.

Comment: Thus, put it shortly : no, the resulting value will likely be just garbage in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answers !!